# General solution of a simple PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

What is the general solution of this equation:

$Q \frac{\partial C}{\partial V} + r = \frac{\partial C}{\partial t}$

where Q and r are constants?

I tried to use the method of separation of variables but it doesn't work. Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Have you read about the method of characteristics? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics

Comment: Not really to be honest, I am not expert in PDE. But let me read through it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewriting your equation a little, we have 
$$ \partial_t C - Q\partial_V C = r. $$
This can be written as 
$$ DC\begin{pmatrix} 1\\ -Q\end{pmatrix} = r $$
That is the directional derivative in direction $(1,-Q)^t$ is $r$. So let us consider $C$ in this direction, define $f \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ by $f(t) := C(t, V_0 - tQ)$, we have 
\begin{align*}
  f'(t) &= \partial_t C(t, V_0 - tQ) - Q\partial_V C(t, V_0 - tQ)\\
        &= r
\end{align*}
for any $t \ge 0$. Hence, by integrating 
\begin{align*}
  f(t) &= f(0) + \int_0^t f'(s)\, ds\\
       &= C(0, V_0) + rt
\end{align*}
So, the solution is given by 
$$ C(t, V) = C(t, V + tQ - tQ) = C(0, V+tQ) + rt $$
for some initial function $C(0,\cdot)$.

Comment: Thanks @martini, that seem to do the job!